# Can anything be done to suppress or limit the clickable area of the checkbox in a Matrix block header?

Tags: matrix, control-panel, checkboxes

You know, the one that gangs blocks together but never really gets explained in the docs.

I hate that thing. I hate it because double-clicking (or single clicking) anywhere in a Matrix block header toggles the check. And wouldn't one rather collapse/expand a block by double-clicking than by pulling down that menu?

It can be hidden with CSS (with consequences) but I am wondering if there is something I am missing.

I would love to restrict its behavior to just the far-left checkbox/label area. I think it's a UI mistake to make the entire header the active checkbox area.

Can anything be done to suppress or limit the clickable area of the checkbox in a Matrix block header? (or [Neo](https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-neo))

Comment: I've fixed this in Neo, and will be available in the next release `1.1.1`

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but have you considered posting a feature request on the feedback site?

http://feedback.craftcms.com